# What do all the distributions available in scipy.stats look like?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics, distribution

## Visualizing [`scipy.stats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) distributions

A histogram can be made of [the `scipy.stats` normal random variable](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm) to see what the distribution looks like.

```
% matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
d = stats.norm()
rv = d.rvs(100000)
pd.Series(rv).hist(bins=32, normed=True)
```

[image: normal distribution]

**What do the other distributions look like?**

Answer (score 135, accepted):

## Visualizing all [`scipy.stats` distributions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html)

Based on the [list of `scipy.stats` distributions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html), plotted below are the [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)s and [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)s of each [continuous random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable).  The code used to generate each distribution is [at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559470/what-do-all-the-distributions-available-in-scipy-stats-look-like#new-answer). Note: The shape constants were taken from the examples on the scipy.stats distribution documentation pages.

#### [`alpha(a=3.57, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.alpha.html#scipy.stats.alpha)

[image: alpha(a=3.57, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`anglit(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anglit.html#scipy.stats.anglit)

[image: anglit(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`arcsine(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.arcsine.html#scipy.stats.arcsine)

[image: arcsine(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`beta(a=2.31, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=0.63)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html#scipy.stats.beta)

[image: beta(a=2.31, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=0.63)]

#### [`betaprime(a=5.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=6.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.betaprime.html#scipy.stats.betaprime)

[image: betaprime(a=5.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=6.00)]

#### [`bradford(loc=0.00, c=0.30, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bradford.html#scipy.stats.bradford)

[image: bradford(loc=0.00, c=0.30, scale=1.00)]

#### [`burr(loc=0.00, c=10.50, scale=1.00, d=4.30)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.burr.html#scipy.stats.burr)

[image: burr(loc=0.00, c=10.50, scale=1.00, d=4.30)]

#### [`cauchy(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.cauchy.html#scipy.stats.cauchy)

[image: cauchy(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`chi(df=78.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi.html#scipy.stats.chi)

[image: chi(df=78.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`chi2(df=55.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html#scipy.stats.chi2)

[image: chi2(df=55.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`cosine(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.cosine.html#scipy.stats.cosine)

[image: cosine(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`dgamma(a=1.10, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dgamma.html#scipy.stats.dgamma)

[image: dgamma(a=1.10, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`dweibull(loc=0.00, c=2.07, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dweibull.html#scipy.stats.dweibull)

[image: dweibull(loc=0.00, c=2.07, scale=1.00)]

#### [`erlang(a=2.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.erlang.html#scipy.stats.erlang)

[image: erlang(a=2.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`expon(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html#scipy.stats.expon)

[image: expon(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`exponnorm(loc=0.00, K=1.50, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponnorm.html#scipy.stats.exponnorm)

[image: exponnorm(loc=0.00, K=1.50, scale=1.00)]

#### [`exponpow(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=2.70)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponpow.html#scipy.stats.exponpow)

[image: exponpow(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=2.70)]

#### [`exponweib(a=2.89, loc=0.00, c=1.95, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponweib.html#scipy.stats.exponweib)

[image: exponweib(a=2.89, loc=0.00, c=1.95, scale=1.00)]

#### [`f(loc=0.00, dfn=29.00, scale=1.00, dfd=18.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f.html#scipy.stats.f)

[image: f(loc=0.00, dfn=29.00, scale=1.00, dfd=18.00)]

#### [`fatiguelife(loc=0.00, c=29.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fatiguelife.html#scipy.stats.fatiguelife)

[image: fatiguelife(loc=0.00, c=29.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`fisk(loc=0.00, c=3.09, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisk.html#scipy.stats.fisk)

[image: fisk(loc=0.00, c=3.09, scale=1.00)]

#### [`foldcauchy(loc=0.00, c=4.72, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.foldcauchy.html#scipy.stats.foldcauchy)

[image: foldcauchy(loc=0.00, c=4.72, scale=1.00)]

#### [`foldnorm(loc=0.00, c=1.95, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.foldnorm.html#scipy.stats.foldnorm)

[image: foldnorm(loc=0.00, c=1.95, scale=1.00)]

#### [`frechet_l(loc=0.00, c=3.63, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.frechet_l.html#scipy.stats.frechet_l)

[image: frechet_l(loc=0.00, c=3.63, scale=1.00)]

#### [`frechet_r(loc=0.00, c=1.89, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.frechet_r.html#scipy.stats.frechet_r)

[image: frechet_r(loc=0.00, c=1.89, scale=1.00)]

#### [`gamma(a=1.99, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html#scipy.stats.gamma)

[image: gamma(a=1.99, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`gausshyper(a=13.80, loc=0.00, c=2.51, scale=1.00, b=3.12, z=5.18)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gausshyper.html#scipy.stats.gausshyper)

[image: gausshyper(a=13.80, loc=0.00, c=2.51, scale=1.00, b=3.12, z=5.18)]

#### [`genexpon(a=9.13, loc=0.00, c=3.28, scale=1.00, b=16.20)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genexpon.html#scipy.stats.genexpon)

[image: genexpon(a=9.13, loc=0.00, c=3.28, scale=1.00, b=16.20)]

#### [`genextreme(loc=0.00, c=-0.10, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html#scipy.stats.genextreme)

[image: genextreme(loc=0.00, c=-0.10, scale=1.00)]

#### [`gengamma(a=4.42, loc=0.00, c=-3.12, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gengamma.html#scipy.stats.gengamma)

[image: gengamma(a=4.42, loc=0.00, c=-3.12, scale=1.00)]

#### [`genhalflogistic(loc=0.00, c=0.77, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genhalflogistic.html#scipy.stats.genhalflogistic)

[image: genhalflogistic(loc=0.00, c=0.77, scale=1.00)]

#### [`genlogistic(loc=0.00, c=0.41, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genlogistic.html#scipy.stats.genlogistic)

[image: genlogistic(loc=0.00, c=0.41, scale=1.00)]

#### [`gennorm(loc=0.00, beta=1.30, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gennorm.html#scipy.stats.gennorm)

[image: gennorm(loc=0.00, beta=1.30, scale=1.00)]

#### [`genpareto(loc=0.00, c=0.10, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genpareto.html#scipy.stats.genpareto)

[image: genpareto(loc=0.00, c=0.10, scale=1.00)]

#### [`gilbrat(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gilbrat.html#scipy.stats.gilbrat)

[image: gilbrat(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`gompertz(loc=0.00, c=0.95, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gompertz.html#scipy.stats.gompertz)

[image: gompertz(loc=0.00, c=0.95, scale=1.00)]

#### [`gumbel_l(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gumbel_l.html#scipy.stats.gumbel_l)

[image: gumbel_l(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`gumbel_r(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gumbel_r.html#scipy.stats.gumbel_r)

[image: gumbel_r(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`halfcauchy(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.halfcauchy.html#scipy.stats.halfcauchy)

[image: halfcauchy(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`halfgennorm(loc=0.00, beta=0.68, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.halfgennorm.html#scipy.stats.halfgennorm)

[image: halfgennorm(loc=0.00, beta=0.68, scale=1.00)]

#### [`halflogistic(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.halflogistic.html#scipy.stats.halflogistic)

[image: halflogistic(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`halfnorm(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.halfnorm.html#scipy.stats.halfnorm)

[image: halfnorm(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`hypsecant(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypsecant.html#scipy.stats.hypsecant)

[image: hypsecant(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`invgamma(a=4.07, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invgamma.html#scipy.stats.invgamma)

[image: invgamma(a=4.07, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`invgauss(mu=0.14, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invgauss.html#scipy.stats.invgauss)

[image: invgauss(mu=0.14, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`invweibull(loc=0.00, c=10.60, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invweibull.html#scipy.stats.invweibull)

[image: invweibull(loc=0.00, c=10.60, scale=1.00)]

#### [`johnsonsb(a=4.32, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=3.18)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsb.html#scipy.stats.johnsonsb)

[image: johnsonsb(a=4.32, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=3.18)]

#### [`johnsonsu(a=2.55, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=2.25)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html#scipy.stats.johnsonsu)

[image: johnsonsu(a=2.55, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=2.25)]

#### [`ksone(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, n=1000.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ksone.html#scipy.stats.ksone)

[image: ksone(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, n=1000.00)]

#### [`kstwobign(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstwobign.html#scipy.stats.kstwobign)

[image: kstwobign(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`laplace(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.laplace.html#scipy.stats.laplace)

[image: laplace(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`levy(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levy.html#scipy.stats.levy)

[image: levy(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`levy_l(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.levy_l.html#scipy.stats.levy_l)

[image: levy_l(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`loggamma(loc=0.00, c=0.41, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.loggamma.html#scipy.stats.loggamma)

[image: loggamma(loc=0.00, c=0.41, scale=1.00)]

#### [`logistic(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.logistic.html#scipy.stats.logistic)

[image: logistic(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`loglaplace(loc=0.00, c=3.25, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.loglaplace.html#scipy.stats.loglaplace)

[image: loglaplace(loc=0.00, c=3.25, scale=1.00)]

#### [`lognorm(loc=0.00, s=0.95, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm)

[image: lognorm(loc=0.00, s=0.95, scale=1.00)]

#### [`lomax(loc=0.00, c=1.88, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lomax.html#scipy.stats.lomax)

[image: lomax(loc=0.00, c=1.88, scale=1.00)]

#### [`maxwell(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html#scipy.stats.maxwell)

[image: maxwell(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`mielke(loc=0.00, s=3.60, scale=1.00, k=10.40)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mielke.html#scipy.stats.mielke)

[image: mielke(loc=0.00, s=3.60, scale=1.00, k=10.40)]

#### [`nakagami(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, nu=4.97)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nakagami.html#scipy.stats.nakagami)

[image: nakagami(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, nu=4.97)]

#### [`ncf(loc=0.00, dfn=27.00, nc=0.42, dfd=27.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ncf.html#scipy.stats.ncf)

[image: ncf(loc=0.00, dfn=27.00, nc=0.42, dfd=27.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`nct(df=14.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, nc=0.24)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nct.html#scipy.stats.nct)

[image: nct(df=14.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, nc=0.24)]

#### [`ncx2(df=21.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, nc=1.06)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ncx2.html#scipy.stats.ncx2)

[image: ncx2(df=21.00, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, nc=1.06)]

#### [`norm(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm)

[image: norm(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`pareto(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=2.62)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pareto.html#scipy.stats.pareto)

[image: pareto(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=2.62)]

#### [`pearson3(loc=0.00, skew=0.10, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearson3.html#scipy.stats.pearson3)

[image: pearson3(loc=0.00, skew=0.10, scale=1.00)]

#### [`powerlaw(a=1.66, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.powerlaw.html#scipy.stats.powerlaw)

[image: powerlaw(a=1.66, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`powerlognorm(loc=0.00, s=0.45, scale=1.00, c=2.14)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.powerlognorm.html#scipy.stats.powerlognorm)

[image: powerlognorm(loc=0.00, s=0.45, scale=1.00, c=2.14)]

#### [`powernorm(loc=0.00, c=4.45, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.powernorm.html#scipy.stats.powernorm)

[image: powernorm(loc=0.00, c=4.45, scale=1.00)]

#### [`rayleigh(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rayleigh.html#scipy.stats.rayleigh)

[image: rayleigh(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`rdist(loc=0.00, c=0.90, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rdist.html#scipy.stats.rdist)

[image: rdist(loc=0.00, c=0.90, scale=1.00)]

#### [`recipinvgauss(mu=0.63, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.recipinvgauss.html#scipy.stats.recipinvgauss)

[image: recipinvgauss(mu=0.63, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`reciprocal(a=0.01, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=1.01)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.reciprocal.html#scipy.stats.reciprocal)

[image: reciprocal(a=0.01, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=1.01)]

#### [`rice(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=0.78)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rice.html#scipy.stats.rice)

[image: rice(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=0.78)]

#### [`semicircular(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.semicircular.html#scipy.stats.semicircular)

[image: semicircular(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`t(df=2.74, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html#scipy.stats.t)

[image: t(df=2.74, loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`triang(loc=0.00, c=0.16, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.triang.html#scipy.stats.triang)

[image: triang(loc=0.00, c=0.16, scale=1.00)]

#### [`truncexpon(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=4.69)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncexpon.html#scipy.stats.truncexpon)

[image: truncexpon(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=4.69)]

#### [`truncnorm(a=0.10, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=2.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html#scipy.stats.truncnorm)

[image: truncnorm(a=0.10, loc=0.00, scale=1.00, b=2.00)]

#### [`tukeylambda(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, lam=3.13)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.tukeylambda.html#scipy.stats.tukeylambda)

[image: tukeylambda(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, lam=3.13)]

#### [`uniform(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html#scipy.stats.uniform)

[image: uniform(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`vonmises(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, kappa=3.99)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.vonmises.html#scipy.stats.vonmises)

[image: vonmises(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, kappa=3.99)]

#### [`vonmises_line(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, kappa=3.99)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.vonmises_line.html#scipy.stats.vonmises_line)

[image: vonmises_line(loc=0.00, scale=1.00, kappa=3.99)]

#### [`wald(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wald.html#scipy.stats.wald)

[image: wald(loc=0.00, scale=1.00)]

#### [`weibull_max(loc=0.00, c=2.87, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_max.html#scipy.stats.weibull_max)

[image: weibull_max(loc=0.00, c=2.87, scale=1.00)]

#### [`weibull_min(loc=0.00, c=1.79, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html#scipy.stats.weibull_min)

[image: weibull_min(loc=0.00, c=1.79, scale=1.00)]

#### [`wrapcauchy(loc=0.00, c=0.03, scale=1.00)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wrapcauchy.html#scipy.stats.wrapcauchy)

[image: wrapcauchy(loc=0.00, c=0.03, scale=1.00)]

### Generation Code

Here is the [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org) used to generate the plots.

```
%matplotlib inline

import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 14.0)
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

---

```
# Distributions to check, shape constants were taken from the examples on the scipy.stats distribution documentation pages.
DISTRIBUTIONS = [
    stats.alpha(a=3.57, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.anglit(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), 
    stats.arcsine(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.beta(a=2.31, b=0.627, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), 
    stats.betaprime(a=5, b=6, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.bradford(c=0.299, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.burr(c=10.5, d=4.3, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.cauchy(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), 
    stats.chi(df=78, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.chi2(df=55, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.cosine(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.dgamma(a=1.1, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), 
    stats.dweibull(c=2.07, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.erlang(a=2, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), 
    stats.expon(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.exponnorm(K=1.5, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.exponweib(a=2.89, c=1.95, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.exponpow(b=2.7, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.f(dfn=29, dfd=18, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.fatiguelife(c=29, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), 
    stats.fisk(c=3.09, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.foldcauchy(c=4.72, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.foldnorm(c=1.95, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.frechet_r(c=1.89, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.frechet_l(c=3.63, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.genlogistic(c=0.412, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.genpareto(c=0.1, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.gennorm(beta=1.3, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), 
    stats.genexpon(a=9.13, b=16.2, c=3.28, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.genextreme(c=-0.1, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.gausshyper(a=13.8, b=3.12, c=2.51, z=5.18, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.gamma(a=1.99, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.gengamma(a=4.42, c=-3.12, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.genhalflogistic(c=0.773, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.gilbrat(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.gompertz(c=0.947, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.gumbel_r(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.gumbel_l(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.halfcauchy(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.halflogistic(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.halfnorm(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.halfgennorm(beta=0.675, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.hypsecant(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.invgamma(a=4.07, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.invgauss(mu=0.145, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.invweibull(c=10.6, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.johnsonsb(a=4.32, b=3.18, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.johnsonsu(a=2.55, b=2.25, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.ksone(n=1e+03, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.kstwobign(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.levy(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.levy_l(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.levy_stable(alpha=0.357, beta=-0.675, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.logistic(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.loggamma(c=0.414, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.loglaplace(c=3.25, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.lognorm(s=0.954, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.lomax(c=1.88, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.maxwell(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.mielke(k=10.4, s=3.6, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.nakagami(nu=4.97, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.ncx2(df=21, nc=1.06, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.ncf(dfn=27, dfd=27, nc=0.416, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.nct(df=14, nc=0.24, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.norm(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.pareto(b=2.62, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.pearson3(skew=0.1, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.powerlaw(a=1.66, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.powerlognorm(c=2.14, s=0.446, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.powernorm(c=4.45, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.rdist(c=0.9, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.reciprocal(a=0.00623, b=1.01, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.rayleigh(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.rice(b=0.775, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.recipinvgauss(mu=0.63, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.semicircular(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.t(df=2.74, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.triang(c=0.158, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.truncexpon(b=4.69, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.truncnorm(a=0.1, b=2, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.tukeylambda(lam=3.13, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.uniform(loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.vonmises(kappa=3.99, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.vonmises_line(kappa=3.99, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.wald(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.weibull_min(c=1.79, loc=0.0, scale=1.0), stats.weibull_max(c=2.87, loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
    stats.wrapcauchy(c=0.0311, loc=0.0, scale=1.0)
]
```

---

```
bins = 32
size = 16384
plotData = []
for distribution in DISTRIBUTIONS:
    try:  
        # Create random data
        rv = pd.Series(distribution.rvs(size=size))
        # Get sane start and end points of distribution
        start = distribution.ppf(0.01)
        end = distribution.ppf(0.99)

        # Build PDF and turn into pandas Series
        x = np.linspace(start, end, size)
        y = distribution.pdf(x)
        pdf = pd.Series(y, x)

        # Get histogram of random data
        b = np.linspace(start, end, bins+1)
        y, x = np.histogram(rv, bins=b, normed=True)
        x = [(a+x[i+1])/2.0 for i,a in enumerate(x[0:-1])]
        hist = pd.Series(y, x)

        # Create distribution name and parameter string
        title = '{}({})'.format(distribution.dist.name, ', '.join(['{}={:0.2f}'.format(k,v) for k,v in distribution.kwds.items()]))

        # Store data for later
        plotData.append({
            'pdf': pdf,
            'hist': hist,
            'title': title
        })

    except Exception:
        print 'could not create data', distribution.dist.name
```

---

```
plotMax = len(plotData)

for i, data in enumerate(plotData):
    w = abs(abs(data['hist'].index[0]) - abs(data['hist'].index[1]))

    # Display
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    ax = data['pdf'].plot(kind='line', label='Model PDF', legend=True, lw=2)
    ax.bar(data['hist'].index, data['hist'].values, label='Random Sample', width=w, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    ax.set_title(data['title'])

    # Grab figure
    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
    # Output 'file'
    fig.savefig('~/Desktop/dist/'+data['title']+'.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
    matplotlib.pyplot.close()
```

Comment: Went above and beyond for this answer!

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Thanks, all the linking and images just involved a lot of your name, lol.

Comment: It's cool! This is the most comprehensive one I have ever seen.

Comment: @tmthydvnprt Thank you for all this code. This really helps me understand the continuous distributions. I was wondering -- as a follow-up from another answer you gave -- do you know how we can test for a best fit of discrete distributions in scipy.stats such as binom or poisson in your solution here? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python/37616966#comment85789076_37616966)?

Comment: Someone give this dude a medal!

Answer (score 13):

### Visualizing all scipy probability distributions in a single figure

Here is a solution that displays all the scipy probability distributions in a single figure and avoids the need to copy-paste (or web scrape) the distribution shape parameters by extracting them instead from the [`_distr_params`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distr_params.py) file that contains sane parameters for all the available distributions.

Similarly to the accepted answer, a sample of random variates is generated for each distribution. These samples are then stored in a pandas dataframe where the columns containing identical distribution names are renamed (based on [this answer by MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43792894/14148248)) because some distributions are listed more than once with different parameter definitions (e.g. kappa4). This way, the samples can be plotted using the convenient [`df.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) function which creates a grid of histograms. These plots are then overlaid with a line plot representing the probability density function ranging from the 0.1% quantile up to the 99.9% quantile.

There are a few additional things to point out:

- The location and scale parameters are set at the default values (0 and 1) for all the distributions.
- Some histograms show only a few very wide bars because of one or more outliers that are located outside of the 0.1-99.9% quantile limits.
- The plot width is limited to only 10 inches in this example so as to preserve the sharpness of the uploaded image. Because of this, you may notice that a few of the x labels (used as subtitles) overlap.
- There is no need to import `matplotlib.pyplot` seeing as the matplotlib objects are generated with the pandas plotting functions (unless you need `plt.show`).

The code for generating the x labels and the random variables is based on the accepted answer by tmthydvnprt and [this answer by Adam Erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640468/14148248) in addition to [the scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html).

```
import numpy as np         # v 1.19.2
from scipy import stats    # v 1.5.2
import pandas as pd        # v 1.1.3

pd.options.display.max_columns = 6
np.random.seed(123)
```

```
size = 10000
names, xlabels, frozen_rvs, samples = [], [], [], []

# Extract names and sane parameters of all scipy probability distributions
# (except the deprecated ones) and loop through them to create lists of names,
# frozen random variables, samples of random variates and x labels
for name, params in stats._distr_params.distcont:
    if name not in ['frechet_l', 'frechet_r']:
        loc, scale = 0, 1
        names.append(name)
        params = list(params) + [loc, scale]
        
        # Create instance of random variable
        dist = getattr(stats, name)
        
        # Create frozen random variable using parameters and add it to the list
        # to be used to draw the probability density functions
        rv = dist(*params)
        frozen_rvs.append(rv)
        
        # Create sample of random variates
        samples.append(rv.rvs(size=size))
        
        # Create x label containing the distribution parameters
        p_names = ['loc', 'scale']
        if dist.shapes:
            p_names = [sh.strip() for sh in dist.shapes.split(',')] + ['loc', 'scale']
        xlabels.append(', '.join([f'{pn}={pv:.2f}' for pn, pv in zip(p_names, params)]))

# Create pandas dataframe containing all the samples
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(samples).T, columns=[name for name in names])
# Rename the duplicate column names by adding a period and an integer at the end
df.columns = pd.io.parsers.ParserBase({'names':df.columns})._maybe_dedup_names(df.columns)
```

```
df.head()

#       alpha     anglit    arcsine  ...  weibull_max  weibull_min   wrapcauchy
# 0  0.327165   0.166185   0.018339  ...    -0.928914     0.359808     4.454122
# 1  0.241819   0.373590   0.630670  ...    -0.733157     0.479574     2.778336
# 2  0.231489   0.352024   0.457251  ...    -0.580317     1.312468     4.932825
# 3  0.290551  -0.133986   0.797215  ...    -0.954856     0.341515     3.874536
# 4  0.334494  -0.353015   0.439837  ...    -1.440794     0.498514     5.195171
```

```
# Set parameters for figure dimensions
nplot = df.columns.size
cols = 3
rows = int(np.ceil(nplot/cols))
subp_w = 10/cols  # 10 corresponds to the figure width in inches
subp_h = 0.9*subp_w

# Create pandas grid of histograms
axs = df.hist(density=True, bins=15, grid=False, edgecolor='w',
              linewidth=0.5, legend=False,
              layout=(rows, cols), figsize=(cols*subp_w, rows*subp_h))

# Loop over subplots to draw probability density function and apply some
# additional formatting
for idx, ax in enumerate(axs.flat[:df.columns.size]):
    rv = frozen_rvs[idx]
    x = np.linspace(rv.ppf(0.001), rv.ppf(0.999), size)
    ax.plot(x, rv.pdf(x), c='black', alpha=0.5)
    ax.set_title(ax.get_title(), pad=25)
    ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabels[idx], fontsize=8, labelpad=10)
    ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=9)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.8, wspace=0.3)
```

[image: scipy_distributions]