# Loop is reading iterable object as string

Tags: python, loops

I am running a loop.

The formula is reading an iterable object as a string.

```
dist_names = ['Lognorm','Weibull']

for i in dist_names:
    param = scipy.stats.i.fit(data)
```

I want the formula above to be 'scipy.stats.Lognorm.fit(data)'.

How can I make the 'i' be read as 'Lognorm'

Thanks!

Comment: Something like `getattr(scipy.stats, i)().fit(data)` should work - but you would want to have lower-case "lognorm" rather than "Lognorm": https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string

Comment: the getattr has the same issue.     param = scipy.stats.getattr(scipy.stats, i)().fit(data)     results in the same error.  module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'getattr'   thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Can you try the code in my original comment? Not `scipy.stats.getattr...` but `getattr(scipy.stats, ... `

Comment: <<<dist_names = results['Distribution']
for i in dist_names:
    getattr(scipy.stats, i)().fit(data)>>> results in the error _parse_args() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'c'

Comment: Right, so it looks like your particular distribution needs parameters when instantiating it - you can see a wide range of them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559470/what-do-all-the-distributions-available-in-scipy-stats-look-like. For example if `i` is `'alpha'` then you'd want to be doing something like `getattr(scipy.stats, i)(a=3.57, loc=0.00, scale=1.00).fit(data)`. To be honest, the variation in parameters between different distributions makes a generic loop approach like this a bit tricky, unless you know that all your dists use the same named parameters.

Comment: hmm thanks but i don't think this approach will work. I might just need to do it manually unfortunately. I thought there was some way to use 'inter' but i don't know.

Comment: I figured out what you meant, thanks!!!